# How to develop calendars for Microsoft project

Tags: plugins, calendar, ms-office, office-addins, ms-project

Microsoft project currently supports default calenders (Gregorian, Hijri, ...).
You can switch calendars from:
File > option > display > calender type

When the calendar changes, all months and weekday names change according to the selected calendar throughout Microsoft project.

**The question is:** How to develop new Calenders to be used in Microsoft project?

I expect the road map of developing new Calenders (as 3rdparty plugins) to be used in Microsoft project.

Comment: It does not appear that additional calendar types can be added. Perhaps [Display an alternate calendar](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/display-an-alternate-calendar-8cb201d4-c175-4d9e-9d8f-b4df00ca8f82) will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, but currently there are some 3rd party plugins: https://mrplanner.ir/product/%d9%81%d8%a7%d8%b1%d8%b3%db%8c-%d8%b3%d8%a7%d8%b2-%d9%85%d8%a7%db%8c%da%a9%d8%b1%d9%88%d8%b3%d8%a7%d9%81%d8%aa-%d9%be%d8%b1%d8%a7%d8%ac%da%a9%d8%aa-%d9%be%d8%b1%d9%86%db%8c%d8%a7%d9%86/

Comment: Another one: https://samix.org/product/microsoft-project/

Comment: And: https://parsinasoft.ir/%D9%85%D8%B9%D8%B1%D9%81%DB%8C-%D8%AA%D9%82%D9%88%DB%8C%D9%85-%D8%B4%D9%85%D8%B3%DB%8C-%D9%85%D8%A7%DB%8C%DA%A9%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%81%D8%AA-%D9%BE%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%AC%DA%A9%D8%AA/

Comment: Interesting! The second one sounds like perhaps it isn't adding a new 'calendar type' but rather new calendars (like base calendars). But I don't read Farsi so I can only understand a little of what the website says.